# Find and substitute values from XML files

Tags: c#, xml, replace

I'm trying to automate the replacement of translations from one XML file to another. The original translator set the translation in the wrong files, and I'm trying to restore them back with an automated process. The original files are like this:

```xml
    <version major="3" minor="6" revision="3" build="1" />
    <region id="TranslatedStringKeys">
        <node id="root">
            <children>
                <node id="TranslatedStringKey">
                    <attribute id="Content" type="28" handle="ls::TranslatedStringRepository::s_HandleUnknown" value="Spanish 1" />
                    <attribute id="ExtraData" type="23" value="" />
                    <attribute id="Speaker" type="22" value="" />
                    <attribute id="Stub" type="19" value="True" />
                    <attribute id="UUID" type="22" value="AAA" />
                </node>
                <node id="TranslatedStringKey">
                    <attribute id="Content" type="28" handle="ls::TranslatedStringRepository::s_HandleUnknown" value="Spanish 2" />
                    <attribute id="ExtraData" type="23" value="" />
                    <attribute id="Speaker" type="22" value="" />
                    <attribute id="Stub" type="19" value="True" />
                    <attribute id="UUID" type="22" value="BBB" />
                </node>
            </children>
        </node>
    </region>
```

```
<content contentuid="h5f6c914fg7db0g4763g9731g58a5eb60c6ab" Source="1.lsb" Key="AAA">English1</content>
<content contentuid="h95735cfdgc22cg4d38g9679ge071f18d77aa" Source="1.lsb" Key="BBB">English2</content>
```

My goal would be to compare the value of the attribute 'value' in the attribute which id="UUID" to the Key of each 'content' node, and if it is the same then substitute the value of each 'content' node with the value of the attribute 'value' in the attribute which id="Content", so that it ends like:

```
<content contentuid="h5f6c914fg7db0g4763g9731g58a5eb60c6ab" Source="1.lsb" Key="AAA">Spanish 1</content>
<content contentuid="h95735cfdgc22cg4d38g9679ge071f18d77aa" Source="1.lsb" Key="BBB">Spanish 2</content>
```

I have tried to operate with **C#** and Xml.Linq but I have lots of errors in the build of my code since my experience with it is very limited.

Thank you for your help and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same issue, I found a solution to it:

```
        XmlDocument docMain = new XmlDocument();
        XmlDocument docCommon = new XmlDocument();
        docMain.Load("spanish.xml");
        docCommon.Load("COMMON.xml");
       
        foreach (XmlElement elem in docMain.FirstChild)
        {
            if (elem.GetAttribute("Key") != "")
            {
                foreach (XmlElement att in docCommon.SelectNodes("descendant::save/region/node/children/node"))
                {
                    XmlNodeList AttList = (XmlNodeList)att.ChildNodes;
                    XmlElement trans = (XmlElement) AttList.Item(0);
                    XmlElement UUID = (XmlElement)AttList.Item(4);
                    if (elem.GetAttribute("Key") == UUID.GetAttribute("value"))
                    {
                        elem.InnerText= trans.GetAttribute("value");
                    }
                    else { }
                }
            }
            else { }
        }

        docMain.Save("modified.xml");
```

Feel free to add suggestions in order to optimise code if you feel like it.

Comment: Please mark your answer as the answer so that the question is closed.